# How can you change the driver for the Laravel basic authentication middleware?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I would like to use the basic authentication middleware from Laravel, except not use a database behind it.

> By default, the auth.basic middleware will use the email column on the
>   user record as the "username".

Is there a way to change this to the filesystem or something other so I can simply add a username and password in a file somewhere. I just need simply security and my data is in an Elasticsearch server so I have no need for a MySQL database behind Laravel.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication#http-basic-authentication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a new middleware. See https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/middleware#registering-middleware

Inside your custom middleware, you can use your own custom authentication classes, which includes file io.

Then, put your authenticated routes inside that custom middleware route group.